# AlarmManager is not waking up at calendar set time

Tags: android, calendar, notifications, alarmmanager

I have set the alarmManager to wakeup at exact 8AM using calendar. 
I set the calendar field as

```
alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
        alarmStartTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);
```

and called the alarmManger like

```
alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis(), getInterval(), pendingIntent);
```

It doesn't wake up at 8:00. Whenever I run the app for first time, instantly the notification will come what ever the time I set up in calendar and called as

```
alarmStartTime.getTimeInMillis()
```

Why is it not starting at exact time?

Comment: where is your Broadcast receiver?

Comment: AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below code, it will help you.

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, stid, alarmIntent, 0);

AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context. ALARM_SERVICE);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 05);

/* Repeating on every 20 minutes interval */
manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),1000 * 60 * 60 *24, pendingIntent);
```

Comment: Hi Ankit, It will repeat on every 20 minutes interval or 1 day interval??

Comment: Thanks, I think it will work for me. I checked for now but I need to verify 2 days so that one notification each day at 8AM. Anyways thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 00);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 00);

Intent alarmintent = new Intent(AddAlarm.this, AlarmReceiver.class); //Intent to Broadcast receiver class

        PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AddAlarm.this, pen, alarmintent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), sender);
```

And in the Broadcast receiver, ie `AlarmReceiver.class`, you can do:

```
    public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        //this will update the UI with message
        AlarmActivity inst = AlarmActivity.instance();
        inst.setAlarmText("Alarm! Wake up! Wake up!");

        //this will sound the alarm tone
        //this will sound the alarm once, if you wish to
        //raise alarm in loop continuously then use MediaPlayer and setLooping(true)
        Uri alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
        if (alarmUri == null) {
            alarmUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        }
        Ringtone ringtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, alarmUri);
        ringtone.play();

        //this will send a notification message
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                AlarmService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

hope it helps! happy coding.

Comment: It's working perfect for me! So thought it'd help to solve the problem, that's all :)